# Jquery function is not working for a href id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code in html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete" id="delete-this">X</a>
```

and jquery

```
$('#delete-this').on( "click", function() {
      alert('test');
   });
```

But By clicking `'X'` -> it is not calling Jquery function to alert. I am not sure how to debug this. Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: you're doing something wrong, the code works as posted - perhaps you're loading jquery incorrectly - check your developer console to see what errors are logged

Comment: are you including jquery? is the dom ready before you attach your handler?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, but a better alternative to `href="javascript:void(0);"` is simply `href="#"`.

Comment: yes it is working for another add - $('#addhere').on( "click", function() {
            Contact.addthis('', '');
        });   
<div><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addhere">Add Contact</a></div>

Comment: is there any way to debug this?

Comment: Do you have more than one ID named `delete-this`?

Comment: What errors (if any) do you see in the console?

Comment: I didn't see any errors in console. I was asking help for how to trace the error

Answer (score -1):

Add the jquery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

your code is right -

but you can bind your click on document

```
$(document).on( "click",'#delete-this', function() {
      alert('test');
   });
```

Comment: My code is working for others, but not for delete, is there any way to debug so that I can find out what is wrong?

Comment: But I am asking for hoe to get error - I can't see any error in cosole while clicking